# Add NAs for all ids so they add up to 25 entries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, formatting

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have a bunch of tables I'd like to put side-by-side based on ID, but they have different numbers of rows per id.

eg. Table 1:

```
ID  Value1
1   'hello'
1   'world'
2   'random'
2   'words'
2   'exist'
4   'today'
```

Table 2:

```
ID  Value2
1   25
3   30
3   12
4   11
4   10
4   52
```

What I would like is to add NAs up bulk them up to 4 entries per id (in this example, in the real one 25). So my output would be:

Table 3:

```
ID  Value1    Value2
1   'hello'   25
1   'world'   na
1    na       na
1    na       na
2    'random' na
2    'words'  na
2    'exist'  na
2    na       na
3    na       30
3    na       12
3    na       na
3    na       na
4    'today'  11
4    na       10
4    na       52
4    na       na
```

In the real scenario I have 12 different tables, each which may have any number of rows per id up to 25 (including 0 for some ids) and the rows per id can vary within the table on different ids too.

I'm not sure where to start here, I know how to join the tables together on id, and to leave all rows there, but not how to get 25 per id regardless of how many entries there are for any particular id.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL-Server, so I'm only going to give you a step by step hint. You need to get all distinct values of your `IDs` across tables  then generate 4 dummy rows with each of those `IDs` and use a window function to enumerate your dummy resultset + results within each table like `ROW_NUMBER`  and join on that filling up non-matching values with `na`.

Comment: Thanks, I may be misunderstanding the last bit but would joining on row_number work there? Because eg. if in the resultset table I'm on row 5 (first row of id 2), then in a table row 5 might be for id 5 if the table only had one row per id. So if I joined on row id, would it end up in the wrong row, with all the nas at the end of the resultset table?

Comment: You need your `ROW_NUMBER` to enumerate rows based on your `ID` column. This is done by `PARTITION BY` clause which is a part of window function definition. This way 5th row of table1 would be first row of `id = 2` and 5th row of table2 would be for example second row of `id = 5`

Comment: I'm at step 2 (dummy rows for each unique id), but I can't seem to find anything on how to create multiple entries per id, or at least not for large #s of multiples (some manually do it for each repeat). Does anyone have ideas for this?

Comment: You could for example generate four-element array in the sequence and then unnest it after you have your values to have it 4 times.